# Adding HTML search terms to results page URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Currently I have a search box on `site.com/search.php`. A user enters in a search term and is taken to `site.com/index.php` which displays the results for the search terms. Except, no matter what a user enters, the results page URL will always just be `site.com/index.php` - instead, I want it to read `site.com/search=word1+word2` or something like that so that each page has a unique URL based on the search input.

I also want it to work in the reverse way, so that someone could, in theory, go straight to `site.com/search=query` and it would be the same thing as if they first went to the main search page, typed something in, and hit return.

I'm new to programming and recently started learning about the `.htaccess` file which I understand I'll need in order to do this. I am just at a total loss as to how to do what I want. I know I need some sort of URL re-writing but not much more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach here is to change your search form to use `method="get"` instead of `method='post'`.

This will create a URL like:

site.com/index.php?search=word1+word2...

Simply change the search script to use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` and you'll be all set without any other significant changes. It will also let users directly run searches via the URL.

The only downside of this approach is that it does not create a beautiful URL (i.e. is still shows "index.php")... however, you can easily work around this by using `.htaccess` to rewrite the URL.

Comment: Okay, I was told this elsewhere too, but I'm not sure how to implement it. All I need to do is change the way the search box was created to GET? That just breaks the site for me...

Comment: in what way does it break the site? Could you give me a link? Also, what system are you using to run the search?

Comment: Ah, never mind. I figured it out. Works like a charm! Exactly what I wanted! Thanks!